# Error when trying to do a search with Powershell towards LDAP

Tags: powershell

The above gives:

PS C:\EndurAutomation\powershell\bin> C:\EndurAutomation\powershell\bin\ets_update_constring.ps1
Exception calling "FindAll" with "0" argument(s): "An operations error occurred.
"
At C:\EndurAutomation\powershell\bin\ets_update_constring.ps1:20 char:30
+ $result = $ldapSearch.FindAll <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

```
$ldapDN = "dc=<masked>,dc=<masked>"
$ldapURI = "ldap://<masked>/$ldapDN"


$env = "sqlplus -S <masked> ``@env.sql > env.list"
Invoke-Expression $env
$envData = (Get-Content "env.list")

$envFilter = "(|"
foreach ($env in $envData) {
    $envFilter += "(cn=$env)"
}
$envFilter += ")"

$ldapEntry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($ldapUR, $null, $null,         [System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes]::Anonymous)
$ldapSearch = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($ldapEntry)
$ldapSearch.PageSize = 1000
$ldapSearch.Filter = $envFilter

$result = $ldapSearch.FindAll($envFilter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You already set `$ldapSearch.Filter = $envFilter` so you don't need to call `FindAll` by passing in the filter again.  Try doing this instead as your very last line of code, as it will still have your filter built into it:

```
$result = $ldapSearch.FindAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a typo:

```
$ldapEntry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(
        **$ldapUR**, $null, $null, 
        [System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes]::Anonymous
    )
```

Try

```
$ldapURI
```

instead of

```
$ldapUR
```